# node.js mongodb - how to make insert wait unit connection is established?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

Using node.js and MongoDB to store realtime data stream.  In my program DBSetUp()  driven by `async:series` connects to MongoDB and completes initial setup. DBInsert() inserts data into collection after initial setup is complete. I am keeping these functions separate since there will be numerous DBInsert() calls. I am not sure how to make DBInsert() wait until DBSetUp() execution is complete.

Seems like I can use `async:series` inside DBInsert() to keep looping until DBSetUp() execution is complete before inserting. I am not sure how to implement. Are there better ideas? Much appreciate your thoughts.

code snippet

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var async = require('async');

...

// Connect to DB and get handle to collection using async:series
DBSetUp(); 

// Wait for DBSetup before inserting    
DBInsert(); 

....
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callback of the async series in your DBSetUp, you can call your DBInsert.

```
async.series(tasks, function(err, results) { DBInsert(); });
```

Create a variable that stores the connection to the client and a function that returns the connection mongo connection through a callback. If your connection is defined, it can return the precached connection. Otherwise, it will call DBSetUp, save the connection to the variable, and then the wrapper function will return the connection through the callback. This way you can use the same function to request access to the database without needing to know whether the connection exists or not.

```
var conn = null
getDB = function(cb) {
  if(conn) 
    return cb(null, conn)
  else
    DBSetUp(cb);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that will work if I have all the data to insert. Since I am storing real-time streaming data I am looking for a robust solution.

Comment: Okay, I just added another suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Found solution on node.js google group. Below is the code snippet

```
function DBInsert()`
{
  async.series([
   function (callback) {
      //Check pre-conditons before insert
      ReadyNow("check", function (err) {
          callback();
      });
    },
   function (callback) {
      // Insert
      callback();
    }  
}

Function ReadyNow(something,callback)
{
   setTimeout(function () {
    // check pre-conditions  
    if (#pre-conditions#)  {        
        callback(); 
    }
    else 
    {
   setTimeout(arguments.callee, 20);
    }   
   }, 20);  
}
```

Comment: That's a hackish solution, I'm sorry to say.